# Spring boot - cannot set default Locale

Tags: java, spring-boot, locale, properties-file

I am now developing Spring Boot application (only rest controllers). Each request to my server contains language tag. I would like to send response in specific language according to this tag. Controllers extract those tags from request and provide to service layer as a Locale instance. I have created properties file under src/main/resources, like this:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsXPG.jpg.

My problem is with default language. Regardless of provided Locale, messages returned from properties file are always from AppResources_pl.properties. I think that, problem is with default locale. For now i tryied two different ways and still don't know how to set default properties file to english.

First:

```
ResourceBundle myResources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("AppResources", currentLocale);
String message = myResources.getString("label.error");
```

Second:

```
@Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"));
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource(){
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("AppResources");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

and in service:

```
messageSource.getMessage("label.error", null, locale)
```

Both way returning message but always from AppResources_pl.properties. How can i set AppResources.properties as a default properties file when provided locale is not found under *.properties files?

Answer (score 6):

I found that in `MessageSourceAccessor` default locale is null, so used system locale. This issue appeared in the last versions because about 6 months ago I used provided in original comment configuration with `LocaleResolver` and it's worked fine.

Solved issue in following line `return new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, Locale.US);` (directly passed `Locale`)

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
    final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource res = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    res.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    res.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false); // will force to use specified locale even if locale for current env is different
    res.addBasenames("classpath:messages/validation", "classpath:messages/messages", "classpath:messages/titles");
    return res;
}


@Bean
public MessageSourceAccessor getMessageSourceAccessor(final MessageSource messageSource) {
    return new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, Locale.US);
}
```

Comment: Note that if you then autowire the `MessageSourceAccessor` bean and use `getMessage(String code)`, it will only use the locale you've set here, and won't check the locale context holder's locale.

Answer (score 3):

You can try below:

```
/*
 * Create MessageSource bean
 */
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
  ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new 
  ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
  messageSource.setBasename("classpath:AppResources");
  messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
  return messageSource;
}

/*
 * Create LocaleResolver Bean
 */
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
  CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
  resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en")); // your default locale
  return resolver;
}
```

Comment: Now i'm getting for each locale code this error: ""No message found under code 'error.reportNotFromApp' for locale '*_*'"

Comment: You can put your default locale here: `resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("defaultLocale"));`

Comment: I made this but still getting messages from AppResources_pl.properties instead of AppResources_en.properties or AppResources.properties.

Comment: In /src/main/resources/ folder, did you create 2 message files for 2 language: "AppResources_en.properties" and "AppResources_pl.properties"?

Comment: Yes. For now i have three messagess files: 1.AppResources.properties 2. AppResources_pl.properties and AppResources_en.properties.

Comment: No, you should delete AppResources.properties file. You can refer my app here: https://github.com/yuen26/logistic/tree/master/src/main/resources

Comment: Hey, you can refer this post http://codedevstuff.blogspot.com/2015/05/spring-boot-internationalization-with.html

Comment: I saw this post before i asked here. Still getting english resources only for en locale and polish resources for all other locale.